# Tree structure in html

Tags: html, css

I need to create a tree structure using html and css.

[Structure should be like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TY8c.png)

Current  css and html for this:

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
  }
ul li{
  background: #F4F4F4;
  }
li.active{
  background: #B7E9FB!important;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="drag-folder">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
    <span>TEST1.1</span>
  </a>
  <div class="nested-list">
    <ul style="display:block">                
      <li class="drag-folder">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
          <span>TEST1.2</span>
        </a>
        <div class="nested-list">
          <ul style="display:block">                
            <li class="drag-folder">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                <span>TEST1.3</span>
              </a>
              <div class="nested-list">
                <ul style="display:block">                
                  <li class="drag-folder">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                      <span>TEST1.4</span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="nested-list">
                      <ul style="display:block">                
                        <li class="drag-folder active">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                            <span>TEST1.5</span>
                          </a>
                          <div class="nested-list">
                            <ul style="display:block">                
                              <li class="drag-folder">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                  <span>TEST1.6</span>
                                </a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
 </ul>
```

This structure can have n number of nodes.

Problem:
nested elements width is less than root element width because of left padding (applied padding to display hierarchy), so on hover background color changes only for that particular width.

I want to make width of all li element to 100% of root element so on active background color will change for 100% width of display area, but need to maintain hierarchy.

I would like to have css solution for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just apply your `.active` class to your `a` tags ?
And do something like this : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aptc5vtu/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your CSS like this:

```
ul{
  list-style: none;
}

ul li{
  background: #F4F4F4;
}

ul li a{
  display:block;
}

li.active a{
  background: #B7E9FB!important;
}
```

Comment: Some comment why this particular code is always helpful.

Comment: I need active node to be of full width.

Comment: `li.active a{display:block;margin-left:-100%;padding-left:100%;background:#B7E9FB;}`,  set the first _ul_ element style: `overflow:hidden`, and set the root element(in your html is _body_) and _li_  **background** the same color.